# Equivalent projections and 2-sided ideals in von Neumann algebras

Tags: von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra. For given $x$ in $M$, we put $I_x=MxM$ (the algebraic ideal generated by $x$).

We know that if two projections $p$ and $q$ are equivalent (that is $\exists u\in M$ with $p=u^*u,q=uu^*$) then $I_p=I_q$. What about the converse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The converse does not hold. Take $M=B(H)$. For any two nonzero finite-rank projections $p$ and $q$ (in particular, with different trace, so non-equivalent), you have 
$$
MpM=K_0(H)=MqM,
$$
the (algebraic) ideal of finite-rank operators.

Comment: Thanks, You are right. Just, it seems that $MpM=MqM$ is the space of all finite rank operators (not compact operators).

Comment: Yes, of course. I was thinking of the closure.